# Parallel Docker build with dotnet restore thrashes each other's caches

Tags: .net, docker, nuget

**tl;dr**: can multiple .NET applications be built concurrently on the same NuGet cache?

I have a Visual Studio Solution containing multiple libraries and multiple applications to be hosted in Docker. I want my builds to be as fast as possible, so I involve as much caching as possible. This is achieved in two ways: first, copy only the necessary .csproj files into their respective directories, to have this layer cached as long as I don't edit any .csproj. Can't use wildcards for this copy, because we need BuildKit for the next step.

Then use `--mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages` before each `RUN` instruction to have a reusable NuGet cache on the host between builds:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all required (transitive) project references
COPY src/SampleApp.Common/SampleApp.Common.csproj ./SampleApp.Common/SampleApp.Common.csproj
COPY src/SampleApp.Data/SampleApp.Data.csproj ./SampleApp.Data/SampleApp.Data.csproj

# Then copy ourselves
COPY src/SampleApp.Api/SampleApp.Api.csproj ./SampleApp.Api/SampleApp.Api.csproj

# Restore as distinct layers
# Mount NuGet cache dir as cache in Docker for faster subsequent builds.
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet restore SampleApp.Api --runtime linux-x64

# Copy all required (transitive) project sources
COPY src/SampleApp.Common ./SampleApp.Common
COPY src/SampleApp.Data ./SampleApp.Data

# Then copy ourselves
COPY src/SampleApp.Api SampleApp.Api

# Build and publish the release (needs cached packages to copy on build)
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet publish SampleApp.Api \
    --no-restore \
    --runtime linux-x64 \
    --self-contained false \
    --configuration Release \
    --output ./Publish/SampleApp.Api/

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/Publish/SampleApp.Api .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleApp.Api.dll"]
```

Now this works, even though maintaining the Dockerfile for larger projects becomes a hassle (adding a new library project requires editing multiple lines in multiple Dockerfiles), but there's a problem when multiple projects need to be built at the same time.

The command:

```
docker compose up -d --build
```

Having multiple projects with Dockerfiles like this, shows, after a while:

> => ERROR [sampleapp_api build-env 16/30] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages  dotnet restore SampleApp.Api --runtime linux-x64
>
> #12 34.56 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Could not find file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.linux-x64/6.0.7/**fgp1y1vi.2tu**'. [/app/SampleApp.Api/SampleApp.Api.csproj]

On the second run two projects fail at the same time:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Could not find file '/root/.nuget/packages/runtime.any.system.runtime.interopservices/4.1.0/**q0z4zwua.tf3**
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Could not find file '/root/.nuget/packages/runtime.any.system.runtime.interopservices/4.1.0/**xpvko1tv.2o3**

Probably because the *third* project is restoring that library at that exact time. This is because multiple builds use the same NuGet cache:

> --mount=type=cache,**id=nuget**,target=/root/.nuget/packages

And because NuGet extracts the package's contents with a random filename on every build, clearing what's already in there, on parallel builds, one build clears the other build's NuGet cache, causing the aforementioned build (restore) error.

Now there's a couple of workarounds, neither of which I like:

1. Have each project have its own NuGet cache (`--mount=type=cache,id=nuget-sampleapp-api`, `...,id=nuget-sampleapp-web`, ...). This will blow up the caches on disk, and a few Docker builds will happily gobble up a few GB already. NVMe space is expensive.
2. When running into this error, build the project images manually one by one (`docker compose build sampleapp_api`, `... sampleapp_web`, ...). I'll have to do this for every application image every time a shared project gets updated. Or script it. More scripts, more maintenance, more non-standard build steps, don't like it. And it beats the purpose of a parallelized build.
3. Run the build a couple of times. Yeah but no.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if you can't have some master project (with no or low code) somewhere that has a reference to all your packages and do a `dotnet restore` on that *outside of Docker*, essentially warming the NuGet cache before everything else happens, including the individual mounts. Theoretically you could remove the individual restores and thrashing.

Comment: I notice you have included `--runtime linux-x64` in `dotnet publish` command, which makes me wondering have you restore the packages with the same [--runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore#synopsis). My *guess* is that if you restore the packages in host machine using different runtime with the one you are using in Dockerfile, some runtime-specific files will not be there.

Comment: @Kit interesting take, thanks. I could create a separate build image for this solution, containing all relevant project files and run a restore there, then build the project images on top of that image. It would increase the maintenance overhead because there'll be another file in which I'll have to specify which project files I want to copy. It will also slow the build when I add a package to one project file and only want to build another project that doesn't need that package, but that's fine I guess.

Comment: @Bemm the `dotnet restore` command is also run with the `--runtime` argument.

Comment: @Kit but of course my approach based on your comment won't work with multiple Dockerfiles, as I'll have to build the image first using a separate command. I could script that, but I'd rather not take a platform or even third-party dependency for the Docker build, I'd like to keep it working with `docker compose up --build`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After struggeling with this exact problem for a long time, i finally figured out why this does not work and how to fix it.

This comment lead me to the solution: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7060#issuecomment-732065148

> So if there are concurrent restore operations running, which use different temp paths but they share the same global packages cache, the cache is not really protected with the locking mechanism at all

NuGet uses a temp folder (`/tmp/NuGetScratch`) which you can read about here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders mounting this temp directory along with the global-packages cache fixes the issue.

The exact issue seems to be that NuGet uses the temp directory for a locking mechanism between restore processes, mounting the temp directory allows this to work when restoring in parallel from Docker.

At this point i just mount all the NuGet cache folders like this when doing NuGet restores:

```
RUN \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/NuGetScratch \
  dotnet restore
```

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. I'll get back to it. So given multiple Dockerfiles (multiple distinct projects) and multiple layers (restore, build) this `--mount` fest will have to be copied all over the place?

Comment: @CodeCaster If you are using the `--no-restore` switch on the remaining dotnet commands, you only need to mount `/root/.nuget/packages` since it only reads the already restored packages from there

Comment: I could verify it by disabling docker-buildkit for my compose build: it worked instantly. Having it turned on leads to timeouts when restoring the packages.

Thank you so much for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid race conditions, we need to cache all of the folders used by nuget. To find out which folders nuget is using, run `dotnet nuget locals all --list`. In a Linux Docker container you'll get the following result when you run `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.414-jammy dotnet nuget locals all --list`:

```
http-cache: /root/.local/share/NuGet/http-cache
global-packages: /root/.nuget/packages/
temp: /tmp/NuGetScratchroot
plugins-cache: /root/.local/share/NuGet/plugin-cache
```

These are the paths that need to be cached.

In my build scripts I've approached the problem defensively. I set the [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) that control the above paths using ENV. I also mount the entire /root/.local/NuGet folder. The end result looks like this:

```
ENV NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/packages
ENV NUGET_HTTP_CACHE_PATH=/root/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache
ENV NUGET_SCRATCH=/tmp/NuGetScratchroot
ENV NUGET_PLUGINS_CACHE_PATH=/root/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache
RUN \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.nuget/packages                  \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.local/share/NuGet               \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/NuGetScratchroot                  \
    dotnet restore
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but you can also prevent this by locking the cache when running.

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages,sharing=locked
```

I struggled with this myself in a monorepo and this resolved the issue for me.